# Simultaneous starting -hold_jid jobs on Sun Grid Engine

Tags: linux, sungridengine

How do I start a bunch of SGE (Sun Grid Engine) jobs where some use `-hold_jid` option, but without requiring clever sorting of the order of `qsub` submissions.

If I do this everthing is fine, where job2 waits for job1 to finish:

```
qsub                   job1.sh
qsub -hold_jid job1.sh job2.sh             # OK: job2 waits for job1
```

However if I instead submit in a different order as shown below, job2 wrongly starts without waiting for job1. Presumably because SGE sees there are no job1 to wait for since job1 has not yet been submitted.

```
qsub -hold_jid job1.sh job2.sh   
qsub                   job1.sh             # BAD: job2 does not wait for job1
```

I have tried user hold option `-h` and then releasing the user hold with `qalter`, but releasing user hold seem to also release the `-hold_jid` hold:

```
qsub -h -hold_jid job1.sh job2.sh
qsub -h                   job1.sh
qalter -h U job*.sh                        # BAD: job2 does not wait for job1
```

Building a dependency tree and start to submit jobs from the leaf level would solve my problem. However I would like to avoid this. I am using Sun Grid Engine 6.2u3 on RHEL 6.

Comment: I *think* it may be due to your jobs not being uniquely named on the hold.  For instance job1 technically completed (past job1) and is stored somewhere in the SGE accounting log. So, when you submit job2, even though it has been a while since job1 completed, job2 will still execute. To test, try and name jobs using unique names, or use jobid.

Comment: "but releasing user hold seem to also release the `-hold_jid` hold": with further testing I found out this is not the case. `qsusb` interprets the `-hold_jid` option immediately when the command is issued and not when the job is scheduled. Thus `qsub -h -hold_jid job1.sh job2.sh` command will look for `job1.sh` in the queue, see that there are none, and place job2 in the queue with no hold.

Answer (score 0):

If @Vince is right and SGE really waits for jobs that were not launched yet, the only way to reach your goal would be to add a unique part to all your job names.

Using jobid won't work if jobs are not launched in the right order because you can't guess the jobid of a future job. If job1 was not launched yet, job2 qsub execution could not guess what will be job1 jobid to wait for...

For example :

```
uniqueID=`date "+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S"`
qsub -N "job2_$uniqueID" -hold_jid "job1_$uniqueID" job2.sh
qsub -N "job1_$uniqueID" job1.sh
```

This way, whatever the job launching order, job2 will wait job1.

Comment: Does not work. Exactly same behavior as in my question above, i.e. first launching job1 makes job2 wait nicely, but first launching job2 does not hold it.